# I get an error message 1364 after inserting values into table why?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1364

```
INSERT INTO Werknemer (voornaam, achternaam, geboortedatum, rol, adres, stad, postcode, telefoonnummer, email, dagVanDeArbeid)
VALUES ('Kingsley', 'Ohenewaa', '2010-07-02', 'medewerker', 'Mozartlaan 70', 'Maassluis', '3144 NC', 06-91139070, 'axtt0y7raea@temporary-mail.net', 'Maandag');
```

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'Restaurant_restaurantID' doesn't have a
> default value 0.016 sec

Comment: Then you need to supply an appropriate `restaurantId` or give it an automatic value, such as via an auto incremented column.

Comment: 06-91139070  should be in ' ',   '06-91139070'

Comment: Maybe 06-91139070 should be '+31691139070'  

Comment: Provide complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE Werknemer;` output.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a non-null column `Restaurant_restaurantId` in that table for which you didn't provide a value.